# DataTable width issue+ DataTable search operation in struts2

Tags: jquery, datatable, struts2

Good day to every one.  I have web application built using struts2+hibernate. I am trying to implement JQuery tabs and datatable in representing my tables. Below is the layout of my page. Below are the list of issues.

Issue1:I have put the datatable in one of the tab(div) "View Income". but the datatable is getting populated out of the div area. I am looking to display the datatable in the tab area(marked in red in the blow image).

Issue 2: I have tried to solve the above issue by decreasing the size of the table but no luck. Can some one tell me how can I decrease the size of the table. I have tried like this but no luck.

```
<table class="display IncomeTable" cellspacing="0" width="600px">
```

[image]

issue 3: the search operation of the data table is not working. I am new to datatable so I am not sure If I need to add any additional logic either in jquery or Java to have this feature?. If yes then can some one give me a hint in achieving this.

JSP Code:

```
 <div id="ViewIncome"> // tab
    <table class="display IncomeTable" cellspacing="0" width="600px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Payee</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>         
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JQuery Code::

```
  $(".IncomeTable").dataTable({
      "searching": true,
      "aaSorting":[[0, "desc"]],
      "sSearch": "Search",
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "bProcessing" : true,
    "bServerSide" : true,
    "sAjaxSource" : "refreshIncomeData",
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "aoColumns": [
         {"mData":"description"},
         {"mData":"catergory.userCodeName"},
         {"mData":"payee.payeeName"},
         {"mData":"transactionDate"},
         {"mData":"amount"}
                  ]
  } );
```

struts.xml:

```
<action name="refreshIncomeData" class="com.hibernate.action.DataTableIncomeAction" method="incomeExecute">
        <result type="json"></result>
</action>
```

[image: Data Table layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the 1 and 2 issues. Here is my updated Code. I have just put it in a new div with some specific width.

updated HTML Code:

```
 <div id="incomesViewTab">
    <div style="width:600px">
        <table class="IncomeTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Payee</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(".IncomeTable").dataTable({
    "paging":true,
    "searching": true,
    "bProcessing" : false,
    "bServerSide" : true,
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "info":true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25], [10, 25]],
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource" : "refreshIncomeData",
    "aoColumns": [
         {"mData":"description","bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
         {"mData":"catergory.userCodeName","bSearchable": false,"bSortable": false},
         {"mData":"payee.payeeName","bSearchable": false,"bSortable": false},
         {"mData":"transactionDate","bSearchable": false,"bSortable": false},
         {"mData":"amount","sWidth":"30px","bSearchable": false,"bSortable": false}]

});
```

Data Table view in one of the Tab:

[image]

Let me know If any one need any one more information.

**Note: Issue 3 is still not resolved. Any comments or suggestion are greatly appreciated.**